# How can i run my python script in the background in my VPS

Tags: python-3.x, linux, vps

i have a python script that will take time to finish executing like more than 48 hours, and i dont want to keep my laptop on and my ssh connection throughout that period, My question now is that how can i run the python script so that even when I logout from my VPS, the script will still be running in the VPS

Comment: you can use `tmux`/`screen` on remote server.

Comment: how can i do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nohup command and it will run even if you close the session

```
nohup command-to-run-script &
```

All output will be written to a file named nohup.out